# extract pattern with text editors

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a URL source page like:

```
href="http://path/to/file.bz2">german.txt.bz2</a> (2,371,487 bytes)</td>
  <td><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://a/web/page/">American cities</a></td>
  <td><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://another/page/to.bz2">us_cities.txt.bz2</a> (77,081 bytes)</td>
  <td><a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://other/page/to/file.bz2">test.txt.bz2</a> (7,158,285 bytes)</td>
  <td>World's largest test password collection!<br />Created by <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="http://page/web.com/">Matt Weir</a>
```

I want use text editors like `sed` or `awk` in order to extract exactly pages that have `.bz2` at the end of them...

like:

```
http://path/to/file.bz2
http://another/page/to.bz2
http://other/page/to/file.bz2
```

Could you help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying parse?  (_World's largest porno password collection!_)

Comment: This is an example @devnull :)

Comment: I started working with `sed` and `curl`, So I test these commands. and also `porno` is an example :D

Comment: It's ok, you don't need to explain that much :)

Comment: @devnull we could do it by saying `wget -r <url>` couldn't we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed and grep:

```
sed 's/.*href=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/g' file | grep -oP '.*\.bz2$'
```

Comment: Good one, you could also use `grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' file` for the first part.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper parser. For example, using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
open :F html input.html ;
for //a/@href['bz2' = xsh:matches(., '\.bz2$')]
    echo (.) ;
```

Comment: Thank you...I would check it

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\.bz2\)".*/\1/p' file
http://path/to/file.bz2
http://another/page/to.bz2
http://other/page/to/file.bz2
```